# Cannot print a text with Gosu in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, syntax-error, libgosu

Im sitting here with what I think is a very simple bug I just can not figure out.. Im trying to learn how to make games with Gosu gem with Ruby, but have hit a speed bump. Here is my code.

```
require "gosu"

class Hello < Gosu::Window
    def initialize width = 800, height = 600, fullscreen = false
    super
    self.caption = "Ruby Practise"
    @image = Gosu::Image.from_text self. "My text to print".
                            Gosu.default_font_name.
                            100
    end
    def button_down id
        close if id == Gosu::KbEscape
    end
    def update
    end
    def draw
        @image.draw 0, 0, 0
    end
end
Hello.new.show
```

There is something wrong but I do not know what. I have spent at least 1 hour on it.. It complains on the String, here is the output from terminal.

```
hello.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG
    @image = Gosu::Image.from_text self. "My text to print".
                                              ^
hello.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
```

I do not what I am doing wrong, do some one know? It is probably something really simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use commas to separate function arguments, not dots:

```
@image = Gosu::Image.from_text self, "My text to print",
                        Gosu.default_font_name,
                        100
```

Comment: Ahh it was so simple, fought I had tryed it but I missed it on sertan places. Thank you!